# Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined when using it for DIVs

Tags: javascript

Me again. I modified the code a bit but
I have an error.
Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined. It happens at:

```
slides[this.current].classList.remove("visible");
```

```js
const innerDiv1 = document.createElement("div");
    innerDiv1.id = "innerDivID1";
    //innerDiv1.classList.add("innerDivClass");
    innerDiv1.classList.add("visible");
    innerDiv1.innerText = "1";

    const innerDiv2 = document.createElement("div");
    innerDiv2.id = "innerDivID2";
    innerDiv2.classList.add("innerDivClass");
    //innerDiv2.classList.add("visible");
    innerDiv2.innerText = "2";

    const innerDiv3 = document.createElement("div");
    innerDiv3.id = "innerDivID3";
    innerDiv3.classList.add("innerDivClass");
    //innerDiv3.classList.add("visible");
    innerDiv3.innerText = "3";

 rightButton() {
    let next = document.getElementById("next");
    next.addEventListener("click", () => {
      this.nextSlide();
    });
  }

  nextSlide() {
    const slides = document.querySelectorAll(
      "#outsideCaroussel, .innerDivClass"
    );
    for (let i = 0; i <= slides.length; i++) {
      if ((slides.className = "visible")) {
        slides[this.current].classList.remove("visible");
        slides[this.current].classList.add("innerDivClass");
      }
      if ((slides.className = "innerDivClass")) {
        slides[this.current].classList.add("visible");
        slides[this.current].classList.remove("innerDivClass");
      }
      this.current++;
      console.log(slides);
      console.log(this.current);
    }
```

Note.
this.current = 0 {at the beginning of the code, the index of the current shown div}

Comment: what is this.current

Comment: I added this.current = 0; at the beginning of the code. The current index of the div which is shown.

Comment: That code is really rather verbose and throws errors when I try to run it. Try providing a [mcve].

Comment: The idea is: My first div must have the "visible" class (in CSS it has opacity of 1). The next divs must have "innerDivClass" (in CSS opacity 0). When NEXT is clicked, the second div gets the "visible class", while the first one gets the "innerDivClass". Same goes with the third div. The next div gets the previous div's class.

Answer (score 0):

On your code `this.current` will go outside your sliders divs in this case you have to use the index `i`

```js
nextSlide() {
    const slides = document.querySelectorAll(
        "#outsideCaroussel, .innerDivClass"
    );
// It should check less than slides.length, on equality slides[i] would be exceeding bound
    for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        if ((slides.className = "visible")) {
            slides[i].classList.remove("visible");
            slides[i].classList.add("innerDivClass");
        }
        if ((slides.className = "innerDivClass")) {
            slides[i].classList.add("visible");
            slides[i].classList.remove("innerDivClass");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that method too, it still shows the same error :(

Comment: can you retry it now

Comment: I do not have the error anymore, but all of my divs have "visible" class. Weird.